# Can't get MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS permission on Android Wear

Tags: wear-os, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

While I try to take MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS permission on Android Wear using this code :

```
Intent grantIntent = new   Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
grantIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(grantIntent);
```

I get this exception :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same basic issue as https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199680. Android Wear doesn't implement the system UI required for the user to grant these "super-permissions" (the permissions found on the *Advanced* screen of *Configure apps* on a Marshmallow phone).

Short-term, the solution is the same as for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW: you need to keep your Wear app on `targetSdkVersion 22`. Lollipop doesn't impose the same restrictions on permissions, so you should be OK.

**Note**: this means that the enclosing handheld app also needs to be on 22! If your Wear app uses one of the "super-permissions" and targets API level 22, but it’s packaged in a handheld app that targets 23, installation to the watch will fail. If you’re interested, the error message in logcat is:

```
W/WearablePkgInstaller: Wearable com.myapp has a permission “android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW” that is not granted in the host application.
```

Which isn’t entirely truthful (this happens even if the permission is granted to your host app), but the result is the same: it doesn’t work.

Longer-term, I'd recommend opening another issue at http://b.android.com explaining this issue and requesting the Wear team to add the system UI for it.